# Mover Registro Anterior/Siguiente en DataGridView, C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, datagrid, visual-studio-2010

Estoy navegando en los registros del `DataGridView` mediante las acciones de los botones `Anterior` y `Siguiente`, el método actual que tiene funciona correctamente para desplazarse por cada registro. **Pero he utilizado este código para** [combinar las celdas iguales en DataGridView en Winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30118206/8933039).

**Datos ficticios para ejemplo:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Entonces con el método que tengo se desplaza en los registros uno a uno, pero **necesito que se desplace al siguiente obviando el registro si tiene el mismo valor en la celda, al igual desplazar al  registro anterior mientras no sea igual el valor de la celda**.

Tengo lo siguiente `CurrentCellChanged`:

```
int indice = 0; 

private void myDataGrid_CurrentCellChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (myDataGrid.CurrentRow != null)
        indice = myDataGrid.CurrentRow.Index;
}
```

Botón `Anterior`:

```
private void boton_anterior_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     int anterior = indice - 1;
     myDataGrid.CurrentCell = myDataGrid.Rows[anterior].Cells[myDataGrid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex];
}
```

Botoón `Siguiente`:

```
private void boton_siguiente_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      int siguiente = indice + 1;
      myDataGrid.CurrentCell = myDataGrid.Rows[siguiente].Cells[myDataGrid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex];
}
```

> Para resolver el problema de mover al registro anterior/siguiente si el valor de la celda no se repite, **He intentado lo siguiente:**

```
bool IsTheSameCellValue(int column, int row)
{
    DataGridViewCell cell1 = dataGridView1[column, row];
    DataGridViewCell cell2 = dataGridView1[column, row - 1];
    if (cell1.Value == null || cell2.Value == null)
    {
       return false;
    }
    return cell1.Value.ToString() == cell2.Value.ToString();
}

    private void boton_anterior_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int anterior = indice - 1;

        if (IsTheSameCellValue(0, anterior))
        {
            anterior--;
            myDataGrid.CurrentCell = myDataGrid.Rows[anterior].Cells[myDataGrid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex];
        }
        else
            myDataGrid.CurrentCell = myDataGrid.Rows[anterior].Cells[myDataGrid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex];
    }

    private void boton_siguiente_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int siguiente = indice + 1;

        if (IsTheSameCellValue(0, siguiente))
        {
            siguiente++;

            if (siguiente == myDataGrid.Rows.Count)
                siguiente--;

            myDataGrid.CurrentCell = myDataGrid.Rows[siguiente].Cells[myDataGrid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex];
        }
        else
            myDataGrid.CurrentCell = myDataGrid.Rows[siguiente].Cells[myDataGrid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex];
    }
```

> ¿Cómo puedo resolverlo?

**Entorno:** Visual Studio 2010 - C# (WindowsForms) & .NET NetFramework 4

Comment: ¿Donde te falla? ¿O no te da error pero no te salta la fila si es igual? ¿Podrías poner tu método IsTheSameCellValue? Aquí tienes un ejemplo donde van comparando también si son iguales lo contenido en las celdas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774966/how-to-merge-datagridview-cell-in-winforms/30118206

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano esa es la misma, referencia que he colocado en mi descripción, por favor vuelva a leer la pregunta

Comment: no falla, solo recorre a la siguiente fila o la anterior, y usando método `IsTheSameCellValue` no se desplaza a la correcta luego de comprar las filas, y este método lo coloqué en  la descripción : [combinar las celdas iguales en DataGridView en Winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30118206/8933039)

Comment: pero no se desplaza a la fila correcta que quiere decir? que salta más de una fila, que no detecta que son iguales los contenidos...

Comment: Quiero decir lo siguiente: Ejemplo En la pantalla publicada, al código 1  le corresponden 6 filas, si presiono siguiente debería **saltar a la fila 7 que contiene el valor 4 en la celda** , pero actualmente salta a la fila numero 4 aunque se supone que tiene el mismo valor de la celda código 1. y ocurre lo mismo si me coloco en la fila 7 con **valor de celda código  4**, si intento retroceder, me envía a la fila 4 y luego a la 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo he resuelto invocando al evento `Click` del botón dentro de si mismo y sumando/restando 1 según el botón. `boton_anterior_Click(sender, e);` , `boton_siguiente_Click(sender, e);`.

> De esta forma no voy a mover la fila del `DataGridView` si el valor es igual, solo aumento/disminuyo el indice hasta encontrar un valor distinto en la celda.

En el click del Botón Anterior:

```
private void boton_anterior_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     int anterior = indice - 1;

     if (anterior <= 0)
     {
         indice = 0;
         anterior = 0;
         myDataGrid.CurrentCell = myDataGrid.Rows[anterior].Cells[myDataGrid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex];
         return;
     }
     if (IsTheSameCellValue(0, anterior))
     {
         indice--;
         boton_anterior_Click(sender, e);
     }
     else
     {
         indice--;
         myDataGrid.CurrentCell = myDataGrid.Rows[anterior].Cells[myDataGrid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex];
     }
 }
```

En el Botón siguiente:

```
private void boton_siguiente_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int siguiente = indice + 1;

    if (siguiente < myDataGrid.Rows.Count - 1)
    {
        if (IsTheSameCellValue(0, siguiente))
        {
            indice++;
            boton_siguiente_Click(sender, e);
        }
        else
           myDataGrid.CurrentCell = myDataGrid.Rows[siguiente].Cells[myDataGrid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex];
}
```

> Si alguien propone una solución mas limpia, se lo agradecería.

Answer (score 0):

Si estas utilizando DataSource para popular la grilla con un DTO podes utilizar Lambda, LINQ o en el mismo store para guardar la cantidad de repeticiones de cada registro agrupado (Ej: ID: 1 tiene 6 registros en "Valor" por lo que guardarías 6).

Algo Como lo siguiente:

```
 public class Opcion
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string  Nombre { get; set; }
    public int Repeticiones { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Simula el DTO
        List<Opcion> lista = new List<Opcion>();

        //count 4
        lista.Add(new Opcion { Id = 1, Nombre = "option 1" });
        lista.Add(new Opcion { Id = 1, Nombre = "option 1" });
        lista.Add(new Opcion { Id = 1, Nombre = "option 1" });
        lista.Add(new Opcion { Id = 1, Nombre = "option 1" });

        //count 5
        lista.Add(new Opcion { Id = 2, Nombre = "option 2" });
        lista.Add(new Opcion { Id = 2, Nombre = "option 2" });
        lista.Add(new Opcion { Id = 2, Nombre = "option 2" });
        lista.Add(new Opcion { Id = 2, Nombre = "option 2" });
        lista.Add(new Opcion { Id = 2, Nombre = "option 2" });

        //Recorro el DTO y Seteo mi Lista de Id y Repeticiones para usar en el DataGridView
        List<Opcion> listaConRep = new List<Opcion>();

        int index = 0;

        //Utilizamos GroupBy Lambda para no recorrer toda la lista innecesariamente
        for (int i = 0; i < lista.GroupBy(x => new { x.Id }).Count(); i++)
        {
            //Usamos Count Lambda para setear las repeticiones
            lista[index].Repeticiones = lista.Count(x => x.Id == lista[index].Id);

            //Comprobacion con Console. 
            Console.WriteLine(lista[index].Repeticiones);

            //Seteamos nuestra lista de referencia de repeticiones
            listaConRep.Add(new Opcion { Id = lista[index].Id, Repeticiones = lista[index].Repeticiones });

            //Sumamos nuestro index
            index += lista[index].Repeticiones;
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

}

Luego, en el OnClick de Siguiente o Anterior, puedes buscar en la lista por el Id (El cual tienes en la 1er Columna de la grilla) y utilizar "Repeticiones" para sumar o restar.

Comment: Tu solución podría funcionar, pero como especifico en la descripción solo son datos ficticios los que muestro en pantalla, **¿Que sucede si el `Id` es alfanumerico?**  no podrías sumar o restar, por ejemplo que los códigos sean: `A1 ,A1, A1, B1, B2, A2` Me parece que de esta forma no funcionaria tu solución, lo ideal sería recorrer el `DataGridview` por el indice de la grilla, y no por el valor que contiene. El valor solo lo utilizo en este caso para combinar las grillas.